What kind of insect eggs are these?
I was looking at one of my forgotten old cotton T shirt inside my wardrobe and I saw these spiky things protruding coming out on it's collars and sleeve ends. I tried to pry some off them out but they're really stuck, like it's glued on. I tried to break on of them and the piece slightly had a bloody color inside. I think they are insects eggs, maybe I'm wrong? If they are, should I be worry about these? Like probably infestation problem? Are they still in incubation or are they just empty leftover shell eggs? They're size is like 5mm or so.


Curious indeed. Are you certain that it's not an artifact of manufacture, a weighting added to the hem like is done on curtains with lead-shot? Reason I ask, they look like seeds to me - but maybe someone knows better. They do seem awfully odd, even spacing, all in the hem like that. Was there any evidence of similar structures elsewhere in the wardrobe or on that shirt?

Well, I'm sure they're not seeds or that someone put it inside the collar. Seems to me that whatever it is might came out though the fabric. It's just a simple cheap cotton T shirt and inside the collar they have just an elastic.

Well, I'm stumped. They don't resemble the eggs of the regular clothing moth, or any eggs that I've come across - to me they honestly look like seeds of some sort. I hope that you get an answer to this strange and intriguing puzzle. If you get it off-site then please pop-in and update the post with an answer, this'll stick with me until I know what it is.

hmm..doesn't have to clothing moths while inside the wardrobe. I dry them on outside hanged on clothes line to sun dry. Maybe something came and put them and lay their eggs while they were drying. I'm still sure they ain't no seeds. I'll find and try other sites and if I did, I'll sure to update you on. I hope they don't hatch and become infestation of not.

At least if they hatch they'll be easier to identify! (A few wash-cycles should probably have rendered them inert I imagine).
